# C program that runs a loop from n and goes till 1

Tags: c

Here's a code that runs a loop from `n` till it reaches 1, so if `n=5`, output is 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() {     
  int i, n; 
  printf("Enter value of n: ");     
  scanf("%d", &n); 
  for(i = n; i >= 1; i--) {         
    printf("%d\n", i);     
  } 
  return 0; 
}
```

I want to change the for loop to a while loop, and made these changes

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int i = 1,n;
  printf("Enter value of n: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  while(n > i){
    n--;
    printf("%d\n", n);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

but it starts from `n-1` value, so if `n=5`,output is 4, 3, 2, 1.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dry run the while loop on paper. Execute every step as if you are the computer. You'll see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @user7658121 Please read :http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, you are printing an answer after reducing `n`. Swap lines.
Then you will need to change condition in `while` loop to `n>=i`.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, you are decreasing your number first and the printing the value of n. So, if n=5, it is first getting decremented by 1 then prints 4, again it gets decremented by 1 and prints 3 and this goes on.

```
while(n>i){
   n--;
   printf("%d\n", n);
 }
```

In order to fix it, first print number and then decrease it. Fixed code will be like:

```
while(n>i){
   printf("%d\n", n);
   n--;
 }
```

Comment: Don't forget to change condition in while loop! :)